# is there any way to remove uialertview when app is in foreground when getting push notification?

Tags: push-notification, swift2

I'm using One signal for push notification service. When I get a notification when the app is running I get an uialertview and I never created such alert view and I can't find a way to not show it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your AppDelegate.swift file. You might showing the alert in **didReceiveRemoteNotification**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
    // might have show alert code
}
```